# Who killed this Harry Potter character?

Tags: harry-potter

In Chapter Thirty-One of Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows,

> Fred

dies due to an "explosion" by *someone*. However, I haven't been able to determine who exactly it was that caused his death. Here's the relevant extract from the chapter:

> “You actually are joking, Perce. . . . I don’t think I’ve heard you
>   joke since you were —”
>   The air exploded. They had been grouped together, Harry, Ron,
>   Hermione, Fred, and Percy, the two Death Eaters at their feet, one
>   Stunned, the other Transfigured; and in that fragment of a moment,
>   when danger seemed temporarily at bay, the world was rent apart.
> <sup>*-Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter Thirty-One (The Battle of Hogwarts).*</sup>

Is there any evidence or additional commentary to determine who killed

> **Fred Weasley**

?

Comment: JKR killed him. And she's [sorry about it](http://www.usmagazine.com/entertainment/news/jk-rowling-apologizes-for-killing-off-fred-weasley-really-sorry-201545).

Comment: Percy seems pretty angry at Rookwood shortly after Fred is killed, but that's by no means conclusive – I don't think we have any idea who cast the killing blow.

Comment: @alexwlchan can you explain to me why this question should not be tagged "deathly-hallows"?

Comment: @RedCaio The [tag:deathly-hallows] tag wiki description says it's about the objects, not the book/films.

Comment: @Richard Today, she issued another apology via Twitter. This time, for the death of Remus Lupin.

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - /sigh. Is there anyone she's not sorry for killing off?

Comment: @Richard Voldemort?

Comment: @maguirenumber6 - It's only a matter of time before she goes 'full lucas' and resurrects someone.

Comment: @Richard Shake things up a bit and bring back Merlin!

Comment: augustus rookwood

Comment: What would be really awsome would be that he was killed by accident through friendly fire.

Comment: @dna Why on earth would that be awesome?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

### Unknown, but there's evidence supporting both Rookwood and Bellatrix.

Fred dies due to an explosion of unknown origin, as shown by the quote in your question. We're never told exactly who caused this explosion, so the short answer is **we don't know**.

However, shortly afterwards, we have this:

> he saw many people running backwards and forwards, whether friends or foes he could not tell. Rounding the corner, Percy let out a bull-like roar, "ROOKWOOD!" and sprinted off in the direction of a tall man, who was pursuing a couple of students.
>
> <sub>-- *HP and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 32: *The Elder Wand*</sub>

Now Percy has been involved in the Ministry, so it's possible he'd had experience of Rookwood there and had some particular strong reason to dislike him already. But his reaction seems *very* strong, towards a man he probably hadn't seen for weeks before this day. And he's just lost a brother, which is obviously fresh and raw in his mind. Revenge for that loss would certainly be a strong motivator.

Then a few chapters later on, we have this:

> "What will happen to your children when I've killed you?" taunted Bellatrix, as mad as her master, capering as Molly's curses danced around her. "When Mummy's gone the same way as Freddie?"
>
> "You - will - never - touch - our - children - again!" screamed Mrs Weasley.
>
> <sub>-- *HP and the Deathly Hallows*, Chapter 36: *The Flaw in the Plan*</sub>

Again it's not conclusive evidence, since "going the same way as Freddie" could refer to being killed by Bellatrix or just to being killed, full stop. But then, how could Bellatrix even *know* about Fred? The death of a single young man is hardly noteworthy in that night of horrors, unless you either knew him personally (like his family, Harry, and so on) or were the one who killed him. Why would Random Death Eater feel the need to tell Bellatrix Lestrange that he'd killed Fred Weasley?

And Molly's words also seem to suggest Bellatrix was responsible for Fred. True, she's fighting Bellatrix because the latter tried to curse Ginny, but she didn't actually *touch* Ginny, so the question remains of what she meant by "touch our children *again*". Of course, we can't expect pedantry and careful choosing of words in the heat of battle, so perhaps Molly just mis-spoke slightly. Alternatively, "our" could be more general, referring not just to herself and her husband but to everyone opposing Voldemort, all the victims of people like Bellatrix, all those who'd lost children in this war.

Comment: For that matter, how would Bellatrix even know that it was Fred, and not George, that was killed, even if she was responsible? Unless the missing ear has become common knowledge (as well as who is missing it), the most likely way to know he’s dead is to have seen and heard the family (including Harry here, who’s extra likely to draw Death Eater attention) by him and saying his name. As for “touch our children _again_”, Bellatrix did do a fair bit of touching Ron (that sounded wrong) at Malfoy Manor, didn’t she? And of course, Molly counts Harry as basically one of her own…

Comment: _'Why would Random Death Eater feel the need to tell Bellatrix Lestrange that he'd killed Fred Weasley?'._ The Weasley family is known to be close supporters of potter, and (probably known) to have members of the order, therefore surely taking one down would surely be news and don't you think that some, if not most, of the death eaters would **brag** about it?

Comment: Is there any reason the "our" couldn't be general, referring to the children of everyone opposing Voldemorte?

Comment: @jpmc26 Hey, good point! That's quite possible.

Comment: @JanusBahs: Fred was polymorphed to Harry with the Polyjuice potion during the attack. It's hard to understand how any Death Eater would recognize him.

Comment: @b_jonas What??? I don't remember that at all. Are you sure you aren't getting the Battle of Hogwarts mixed up with the Battle of the Seven Potters?

Comment: Oh... right, I was confusing them. It was another character who got killed in the Battle of the Seven Potters, and he wasn't polymorphed. Sorry.

Answer (score 5):

It is impossible to know, they were in a battle with magic spells flying everywhere, an explosion could have been caused by a death eater aiming at them (unlikely, they were meant to take Harry alive). A death eater who missed his/her target. An ally who missed his/her target. A giant smashing through something explosive. No one knows who fired the shot. Also the explosion probably didn't kill Fred, After all the others survived. It was more likely a wall/floor that killed him.

Comment: I agree that the explosion wasn't what inherently killed him, as there doesn't seem to be evidence of his body being severely damaged. His descriptions seem almost Avada Kedavra like.